# ReactJS: Direct node manipulation and then filtering the node out of state causes manipulation to occur on the next node instead

Tags: reactjs

CodeSandBox demonstrating this behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-feistel-qgy1r?file=/src/App.js

If  `dude1` is clicked, `handleClick` inside of `<Item/>` is supposed to shift `dude1`'s DOM node 10px to the left. After that, the `<Item/>` containing `dude1` is filtered out.

However, it seems like after the `<Item/>` containing `dude1` is deleted, the style of 10px to the left is applied on `dude2`.

I understand direct manipulation is not welcomed in ReactJS, but I am building a rather high level swipeable and reorderable list component that can remove elements on swipe. Currently, if I call `swipedElement.remove()` and then also filter out the `swipedElement` from the array that renders it (which really there isn't any reason to do so, except to stay "Reacty"), the same behavior demonstrated in above sandbox occurs: The next element gets deleted instead.

Link to the swipeable, reorderable list: https://codesandbox.io/s/slippablelist-hm79e?file=/src/App.js. (comment out setData1 in onSwipeEnd to see what intended behavior, swipe for more than 50% to the right to trigger deletion)

Comment: You have to give each element in a dynamic list like that a `key` so that React knows how to keep track of them when they shift. Adding `key={d.id}` fixes the wrong component shifting, but it isn't a complete fix to get your desired behavior.

Comment: There could definitely be a better solution out there, but a quick one I got to work was putting the `handleClick` in a `setTimeout` like this: `setTimeout(() => handleClick(id), 300)`.

Comment: That's so interesting, I didn't know `key` did that, thank you, works now.